# no activity performed on button click

Tags: java, android

I have added a new activity to my application which already had some other activities. I am trying to make my new activity as main activity.when a  button is clicked the previously existing activities should be called.

My problem is when i click the button no activity is performed.

I have made changes in manifest file as well.

My first intent has

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(userName.equals("admin")&&password.equals("admin")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OpenNMS.class);
            startActivity(main);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
});
```

my manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.opennms.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Login"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".OpenNMS" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: are you sure that the condition for the activity to start is true? you have same toast for true and false cases.

Comment: is it entering the `onClick`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you haven't added `show()` to the Toast message,

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

It should be like this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

So, it might be going in your else part where you are not able to see the Toast.

Thanks.
Suri Sahani.

Comment: u r right, its going into else part. I have used loggers only to find that username and password fields are empty..But why is it happening that way

Comment: For that you will have to show me full code, how you are checking the admin details.

Comment: Use equalsIgnoreCase in place of equals, in place if you are having "Admin" as a username or password.

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(userName.equals("admin")&&password.equals("admin")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent main = new Intent(getBaseContext(), OpenNMS.class);
            startActivity(main);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Invalid UserName or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
});
```

you have miss `view`

```
login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
```

to

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Intent main = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OpenNMS.class);
```

to

```
Intent main = new Intent(Login.this, OpenNMS.class);
```

and see if it works.